# Concatenate two files into one without read their content

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

I have two files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Jun 28 11:34 file_a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Jun 28 11:34 file_b
```

I want to concatenate these two files into one.

```
cat file_a file_b > file_c
```

**Above way is not what I wanted. Because it may cost too much time if file_a,b too big**

There should be more efficient ways. File on Linux is stored on my discrete physical area. There should be some data structure (we call it pointer here) recording these physical areas.

By modify the pointer, make the end pointer of file_a to start pointer of file_b, we should be able to concatenate them two into one very quickly.

So question is how to do this in python?

Comment: Linux file systems do not support such an operation. Even if you wanted to try to mess with the internals of the FS, you can't do it unless the files align perfectly with the underlying block size and the file system is umounted. A better approach is 1. to modify the reader to support reading multiple files sequentually, or 2. create a fuse fs that exposes multiple files as a single concatenated one

Comment: If you expect to create a new, third file, while leaving the two original files intact, then what you ask is simply impossible.  However if you want to *append* the contents of **file_b** to **file_a**, then the O_APPEND option can be used in the **open()** syscall to skip to the end of the file.  But that would only leave **file_b** intact, and not create a **file_c**.

Comment: *"By modify the pointer, make the end pointer of file_a to start pointer of file_b, we should be able to concatenate them two into one very quickly."* -- Your claim is false. For the general case, no, this is not correct.  A partially-written block (e.g. sector) is only allowed to exist at the end of a file.  Whenever the size of **file_a** is not a multiple of the allocated block size (e.g. a cluster), then trying to append **file_b** by simply linking it with **file_a** would create a sub-block of invalid data where the files are joined.

Answer (score 0):

`copy_file_range(2)` can do the job. But I think it is [yet](https://bugs.python.org/issue26826) to be exposed in python. The older `sendfile(2)` seems to be available in python via  `os.sendfile`. You'd  have to call it twice, with the **in** fds for *file_a* and file_b each time and the **out** fd for *file_c* .